# Q: If this behavior depends on the initial value of $y$ at $t=0$, describe this dependency.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

[image]

[image]

How do I decide if the behavior depends on the initial value of $y$ at $t=0$ or not?  If it does depend, what does it means by dependency?

Comment: Also, how do I directly enter the image in the question instead of an image link? thank!

Answer (score 1):

Dependency means that changing that initial y value at t=0 affects the function when t approaches infinty. So essentialy, its asking that if I change the intial value of the ODE at t=0, does that affect the limit of that solution as t goes to infinity, and in this case it does